# Favoring static class usage over variable with same name

Tags: java, static, obfuscation

Class B extends Class A, Class A has a variable named K, I have a static Class named "K" also. Is there a way inside class B to favor using the static class K over the inherited variable K?

(I am working with decompiled code that was obfuscated, I cannot rename either of the versions of K)

Comment: Decompiled code, huh? Sounds completely legal (*sarcasm*)

Comment: What do you mean by "static class" - that it's a static nested class?

Comment: Why not simply get the source from its rightful owner? Or if not the source, the API so that you can write utilities and such.

Comment: It is completely legal. Making a mod for a game that supports it's modding community.

Comment: @Zachar which game? Perhaps you could add it to the question. Chances are there's someone on StackOverflow that has dabbled with modding it.

Answer (score 4):

You may need to refer to the class `K` with its full name, ie `myPackage.K`

Comment: Every class has a package. I'll leave it to you to figure out what it is.

Comment: @Kublai every class has a package, but not every class can be referenced to include its package name. That does not apply to K here though, because it is a nested class.

Comment: @Hemal - You're right, I stand corrected. But is it a nested class? the OP never answered my question about that.

Comment: The `static` modifier applies only when a class is **nested**, right? That is why I am assuming it is a nested class. If Y is not nested (and so not static) then there is no problem.

Comment: @Hermal - We could make that assumption though the OP wasn't completely clear about it. I was wondering if you'd seen something I hadn't that made you sure.

Answer (score 2):

Since K is in the default package, I think your only options will be to refer to class K using reflection or else write a class to wrap K so you can use a different name. Or if you're after some static members of K, you could use static imports to get at them, too.

Comment: +1 I didn't know about the limitations on the default package - guess I learned something.

Comment: If A,B,K are all top-level and in default package then any reference to K inside B will resolve to the class K, not A.K. If K is a nested class of B then it can be referenced as B.K, see my reply below

Comment: @Hemal: It depends on what you're trying to do with K, but ambiguous references will go to the field, not the class. E.g. `int x = K.y`, where y is a static field of class K, won't work because K will resolve to the field, not the class. As I think about it, though, I'm thinking if the OP is actually having a naming problem what he/she probably wants is a static import. I think accessing static members is the only place where you'd have a potential conflict.

Comment: @Ryan, I tried it out and it seems as you point out the static members (of the nested static class) are the only place where there is a conflict, but it can be solved by using a dummy variable of the nested type initialized to null.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
class A {
    int X;
}

class B extends A {
    static class X {}
    void foo() {
        X = 5;  // A.X variable
        B.X x = new B.X(); // B.X nested class
    }
}
```